# .net WebBrowser control modifies html?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I am scraping webpages and when I run my scraper application on a windows XP box with IE 8 (it is the max Windows XP supports) it returns different HTML source from webBrowser.Body.OuterHtml than it does when running on Windows 7 with IE9. Does anyone know how to get the raw html unmodified from the webbrowser control??? I know IE modifies HTML so I want to know how to get the raw html returned from the web server. It's annoying because I write the scraper on my windows 7 dev box and then it won't work when I host it on a Windows XP box. If you answer don't tell me to use WebClient and download the page, I want to easily support browsing pages and not have to worry about other little webpage stuff that is taken care of by a webbrowser control. I am using webbrowser control for a reason. Does webBrowser.DocumentText return the raw html or is this still modified html be IE?

Comment: Have you looked into the compatibility and quirk modes? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055271/webbrowser-control-ie8-compatibility-mode-on-off-switch, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646742/how-to-programmatically-turn-off-quirks-mode-in-ie8-webbrowser-control

Comment: It seems like your question is "I know how to download a page from the server with WebClient, but I don't feel like doing it.  Please tell me a way to use a WebBrowser, which is designed for showing a webpage to the user and is not designed for making raw HTML available to the programmer, to get raw HTML from the server."  Why the aversion to WebClient?

Comment: I am using the webbrowser control to handle cookies, sessions, and so I can fill in input fields and submit using POST's and also handle paging links etc easier.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally you have two opposing concerns:

- You want to get the original source, unmodified by anything the browser can do
- You want to let the browser do things, as you apparently find it useful. (You've said you're using `WebBrowser` "for a reason" but you haven't actually told us what that reason is.)

If you *really* need to use `WebBrowser` for some reason, you might want to fetch each page twice: once within the browser (so that it can do whatever you need it to) and once with `WebClient` (so that you can get the response without any messing).

It's also possible that disabling scripting within the browser control would do everything you need it to - but as you haven't given us the reason for using the browser control in the first place, that may not help...