# Is there a way to determine whether IE is a standard browser or an embedded control within C# Form?

Tags: javascript, winforms, internet-explorer

Within the HTML/JS scope, I would like to distinguish between both cases.

I wonder if there is a way find that via some window/doc properties?

Comment: Can I ask why it is you would need to know the difference?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "C# form" - once it's on the client, it's just HTML.

Comment: @Diodeus yet, there might be differences in the API which can be used, isn't there?

Comment: You might be able to detect it from the user-agent in the HTTP header.

Comment: That can be easily spoofed. see http://hynchrstn.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/make-custom-javascript-navigator-useragent/ for instance

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [window.external](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535246%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which provides access to an additional object model provided by host applications of the Windows Internet Explorer browser components. You will be able to define special identifier in native part and then check it from html/js. Similar to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/737b54ee-6478-4354-8a51-bcf2e84256a3/

PS. In case of Windows Phone app you can just check for window.external.notify - exists in hosted web browser control case only.

Comment: I checked that option already.
However, I have no control over the client, only the server side, and the window.external properties are not iterable in a for prop in obj fashion - which makes it hard to guess what new propertied might appear in such case.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is really no sure way to do this.  You can make some guesses based upon the version numbers passed in the UserAgent, but as you mentioned this can be spoofed.

I'm not sure what your exact use case is, but when I found some inconsistencies between the behavior of the embedded control and browser; information in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055271/webbrowser-control-ie8-compatibility-mode-on-off-switch) answer was helpful.