# Internet Explorer and vb webbrowser different?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer, border

Im trying to create a program with all my servers and services pages saved on it, so my problem is:
here's the site in the internet explorer:

[image: Internet Explorer Image]

here's the site in the program:

[image: Program image]

here's the image loged in, on internet explorer:

[image: logged in on internet explorer]

and here's in the program:

[image: loggeed in on program]

can anyone help me? please

best regards.

Comment: You'll need to create your HTML and CSS so the site still works properly with a browser that runs in compatibility mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2055271/362536

Comment: can u explain a litle better im not understanding im starting vb so if u can explain how to do it... thanks

Comment: can any one please help me creating css and html template so my webbrowser in vb work fine please. or just give me an exemple template so i can see.